# Restore SharePoint 2010 Site - Different schema version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, central-administration

I have a backup of a SharePoint site (14.0.6114.xxxx December 2011 CU??) and I tried to restore it to a different farm with version 14.0.6106.xxxx April 2011 CU???. As expected I got the schema validation error because I'm restoring to a farm that has lower version.

Is there a way to export and import the site without checking the version? Is there a switch in powershell or stsadm command that will allow me to ignore the version???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way I know of to ignore the version conflict, you're going to have to restore that backup to a farm (probably in a vm or something) that is running the same version as the backup, then upgrade that farm and create another backup that can be restored into your second farm.

Export/Import may work, but it's not going to directly pull from a SharePoint backup, you're still going to have to have that backup restored somewhere to use as a target.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the feedback. we are using the product DocAVe and using that I was able to migrate between two farms with different versions.